# Java Programming: Turtle not moving in desired direction

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java program in which I have to get the turtle to move West, but what I have so far isn't getting the turtle to move in the desired direction.

```
public static void moveTurtleWest(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for(; n > t.getX();n-- ){
            t.moveWest();
            }
    }
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
package assignment;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import java.time.LocalDate;

/**
 * This class represents a turtle, like a Logo-like turtle, which keeps its position.
 * The turtle keeps its x and y position, and has methods moveNorth() etc which change it
 * Assume normal math coordinates and map convention, so as you move up (North) y increases, and as you move East x increases.
 *
 */
class Turtle {

    // HINT - you may want to have variables to keep the position. Keep these variables private,
    private int x,y;

    // TODO - The empty constructor initializes position to 10,10
    public Turtle() {
        this.x = 10;
        this.y = 10;
    }

    public int getX() { 
        // TODO - implement this
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        // TODO - implement this
        return this.y;
    }

    public void moveNorth() {
        // TODO - implement this. this increments the y coordinate by one unit
        this.y += 1;
    }

    public void moveSouth() {
        // TODO - implement this. this decrements the y coordinate by one unit
        this.y -=1;
    }

    public void moveEast() {
        // TODO - this increments the x coordinate by one unit
        this.x +=1;
    }

    public void moveWest() {
        // TODO - this decrements the x coordinate by one unit
        this.x -=1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Turtle[x="+getX()+", y="+getY()+"]";
    }

    public boolean equals(Turtle t)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        // two turtles are equal if their X and Y coordinates are equal.
        if (t == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(t instanceof Turtle)) {
            return false;
        }
        return (x == ((Turtle) t).x && y == ((Turtle) t).y);
    }

    public void move(String direction)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        // move to the right direction; direction can be North, South, East, West
        moveEast();
    }
}

public class Assignment7 {
    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the West, n times
    public static void moveTurtleWest(Turtle t, int n)
    {
        for(; n > t.getY();n-- ){
            t.moveWest();
            }
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the East, n times
    public static void moveTurtleEast(Turtle t, int n)
    {
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the North, n times
    public static void moveTurtleNorth(Turtle t, int n)
    {
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the given turtle to the South, n times
    public static void moveTurtleSouth(Turtle t, int n)
    {
    }

    // TODO - you need to implement this. Move the turtle to the asked position, by calling MoveXXX etc
    public static void moveTurtleTo(Turtle t, int x, int y)
    {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you can use this as you wish to test or exercise your function. Not graded.
        Turtle t=new Turtle();
        moveTurtleTo(t,15,16);
        System.out.println(t);  
    }
}
```

Here is the code that is executing when I run this method in git Bash:

```
public void testMoveWest()
    {
        Turtle t=new Turtle();
        t.moveWest();
        t.moveWest();
        t.moveWest();
        t.moveWest();

        Assert.assertEquals(6,  t.getX());
    }

    @Grade(points=10)
    @Test
```

Any help is appreciated and points will be rewarded.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it the opposite direction than what you expect? Is this done via GUI (like Swing) interface?

Comment: No, I'm running a script in GitBash in which if my code executes, then I will be awarded 10 points, so I'm running my validation and compiler via command line.

Comment: so the test that you have mentioned that itself if not passing?

Comment: Exactly the test is not passing

Comment: can you print the value of getX() in that test? or you can find the same in the output of assertEquals fail.

Comment: The test is not passing because the for loop I wrote up top is incorrect because the public void testMoveWest is not executing.

Comment: No I cannot print the value of getX() in that test. My code compiles it is just not executing the  public void testMoveWest correctly because I'm not getting the 10 points.

Comment: so your actual problem is that for loop is incorrect. I  dont see anything wrong in your moveWest method.

Comment: Yes but I need something in the 
public static void moveTurtleWest(Turtle t, int n) method in order for my program to work correctly.
I need a for loop or something to get this method working please

Comment: try the loop which I have mentioned in answer and let me know whether your test passes properly or not.

Comment: It passed!
Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly correct for loop:

```
 public static void moveTurtleWest(Turtle t, int n) {
         for(int i=0; i <n;i++ ){ 
               t.moveWest(); 
          } 
 }
```

Comment: Great Job!. I greatly appreciate all of the help!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the predicate in the for loop be t.getX() instead of t.getY()?

Comment: Yes it should be and I made the change but it is still not working